# Identify the next symbol in the pattern

Tags: pattern, visual

[image]

---

### *Which symbol should replace the question mark in the above pattern?*

To clarify a few things:

- You can solve this puzzle with a printed version of it; that is to say, there's no steganography or other means of encryption involved here.
- The square layout of the tiles is irrelevant. They go in a specific order, and this puzzle could just as well be solved with the tiles laid out in a straight line.
- There is no 'misleading' information in the puzzle. Every single piece of the puzzle is relevant to its solution.
- The pattern will be obvious once you discover it. If at any point it feels like a stretch, or you seem uncertain about anything, you're on the wrong track.

---

Hint 1:

> Try not to get too caught up on the word *pattern*. Looking for patterns in the colors will most likely not get you to the right answer.

Hint 2:

> 1  2  3
>  4  5  6
>  7  8  9

Hint 3:

> This puzzle would work in black and white - the colors simply add a nuance.

Comment: I feel like the answer should be B, but I can't justify it.

Comment: `The square layout of the tiles is irrelevant. They go in a specific order...`  Then I think you should clarify the order.  Should we read these tiles by rows or by columns?  The answer given by `Player One` assumes reading by columns (where 1 yellow + 3 purples was 2nd tile), but my natural tendency was to read by rows (where 2 blue +  2 orange was the 2nd tile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is B,

> The dots are a binary representation of the digits in the golden ratio (1.61803398), with each primary color representing a 1, and secondary colors are a 0.

So,

> 0001 0110 0001 1000 0000 0011 0011 1000, and the only block that could be 1000 is B, Yellow Purple Purple Purple.

Edit: looks like I was beaten.

Second edit:

> the primary/secondary color pairs are also opposites on the color wheel. Starting with '1', the colors cycle through red yellow blue as the digit's primary color for the binary encoding

Comment: You added a bit of explanation about the colors. I'll +1 your answer, but I'll accept the first answer than can explain exactly how the colors were chosen to represent their specific numbers!

Comment: @baileym added another note about the colors

Comment: @baileym also, you said the puzzle would work without color, so wanting specific color pairs for each digit is kinda off, don't you think?

Comment: What I meant was that the base idea of the puzzle didn't involve the colors. The colors are a secondary part of the puzzle, which do have a reason to their rhyme as well.

Comment: starting with '1', the colors cycle through red yellow blue as the digit's primary color for the binary encoding

Comment: They most certainly do! Add that to your answer, and I can accept it. :) (P.S. it's based on the numpad layout)

Comment: @BaileyM updated

Comment: There is a typo in your last 4 digits. It should be 1001

Answer (score 4):

An attempt of an answer is **B** because

> Splitting the pattern into 9 "fields", each field consists of two "complimentary" colours. Red/Green Blue/Orange Purple/Yellow. Each of the fields is either a duplicate or the colour-inverse of another, with the central all-green tile being an exceptional piece. (As there are an odd number of tiles, one has to be a "stand-alone" item. Central and of one colour only seems to be an appropriate choice.) This leaves the tile which looks like the "B" tile to require a double or an inverse, and tile B is the only one fulfilling this requirement.

A simpler way of seeing it:

> All tiles on the left need a duplicate on the right. The central column is symmetric and otherwise just a distraction.

Comment: While this is certainly valid reasoning, it is not the explanation I'm looking for. Each tile is meaningful to the final solution. :)

Comment: I was afraid it would be so. Not seeing it (yet) though.

Answer (score 4):

It can only B

> the decimal digits of the golden ratio, expressed in binary

Comment: That's more like it. :) Can you explain the color scheme?

Comment: If you're treating zero as the last digit (for toots and giggles maybe), then I would guess two and five should be yellow/purple while four and seven should be red/green.

Answer (score 2):

<s>The Answer is C, because:</s>

Well their is so much data that can prove it, that will take at least one hour to enumerate all of them, so I will just write the most obvious one:

> You need to calculate the number of identical colors from the start of each symbol until they change.here the pattern: 3|1|3...1|4|2...2|1|4 (each row must be equal to 7)

I have edited my answer after reading this:

> *"The square layout of the tiles is irrelevant."*

So now, the answer is **B**:

> You need to calculate the number of **colors switching** in each tiles, the pattern is: 1/2/1/1/0/1/1/2/1

Some explanation about how I come to this answer:

> **First**, we need to now what we have here:  6 different colors, 8(+1) tiles, 4 colored circle in each tiles, Only one colored circle can link another one, only one tiles is fully filled with only one color, colors have their own pattern (green + red, orange + blue, yellow + purple), only the (orange + blue) pattern are equal (2 of each of them in their tiles). **Now**, we can start conceptualizing the pattern by asking some question: does those colored circle linked each others mean we need to read them like this (bottom-left > top-left > top-right > bottom-right) ? **If yes,** does we can say they are like rainbow ? **If yes,** RED=1,ORANGE=2,YELLOW=3,GREEN=4,BLUE=5,PURPLE=6 ? **If yes,** does that mean that each color pattern is equally distanced by 3 (Green = 4 / Red = 1, Orange = 2 / Blue = 5, Yellow = 3 / Purple = 6)? **If yes,** that mean 3 must be our delimiter for calculating our pattern ? **If yes,** can we say that we need to read 3 tiles by 3 tiles ? **If yes,** we can easily see that each of those 3 row of tiles are hugely different in term of colors and number of same colors, right ? **If yes,** does we will need to read by a logical order following the *"arc / rainbow line"* ? **If yes,** that will mean that the type of colors, the color at the start/end and the order of them in the tile is **Irrelevant** ? **If yes**, this will indicate that only the **colors switching** is relevant ? **If yes**, how can we calculate it ? **Maybe**, by giving to each tile a point for every color switched, in example: (green,green,green,red = 1) / (orange,blue,blue,orange = 2) / etc....  **By this theory, only one symbol can be our next symbol in the pattern**: **B** --Since B is the only tiles with 1pts color switching in those suggested symbol.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling zaykho. This is a good start to a solution, however I suggest that you add more explanation behind how your answer works and how others can use your answer.

Comment: I do understand your solution (and like the idea.) If English is hard, you may also try a *visual* solution. Draw (or copy & modify) the image and add the numbers...

Comment: Added a new answer after reading this : *The square layout of the tiles is irrelevant.* Also, I have detailed to the maximum (took 20 minutes to post lol)!

Comment: Also, with this theory, whatever how we read it (by column or row) the final pattern is always good !

Answer (score 1):

If we read the squares in order as

```
147
258
369
```

Then the patterns go (with bold as the start of a repitition and italic as the inferred next in series)

Green/Red:

> green+red, skip 3, all green, skip 1, **green + red**, *skip 3, all green, ...*

Purple/Yellow:

> Not really much information on this one, but skip at least 6

Orange/Blue:

> Orange left + blue right, orange bottom + blue top, skip 1, orange top + blue bottom, skip 1, **orange left + blue right**, *orange bottom + blue top, skip 1, ...*

Therefore I think the answer is

> D

Comment: I added a clarification on the puzzle itself, but to make sure you see it: "The pattern will be obvious once you discover it. If at any point it feels like a stretch, or you seem uncertain about anything, you're on the wrong track." :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading each unit as a series of four colored nodes, the number of color changes in each unit is represented below in square form:

```
121
101
12?
```

As zaykho points out, there is clear symmetry here no matter whether you read the units left-to-right, up-to-down, or as a square.
Only one of the options fits this symmetry:

> Answer B, which has 1 color change.

Answer (score -1):

All tiles need to be there twice, either as exact matches or a reflection, except for the all green in the middle which appears once. Taking the tiles as numbered
123
456
789
1 and 3 match exactly;
2 and 8 match as a reflection;
6 and 7 match exactly;
the only one missing is 4, so the answer is B

Comment: Creating exceptions for 3/8 of the given shapes (one pair and the center one, each with their own exception) seems to make this a poorer rule than those found before.